# Undefined value when adding data from JSON to array using .push()

Tags: javascript, json, p5.js

I'm getting JSON data from [this](http://hitchwiki.org/maps/api/?continent=AF) API. My code looks like this:

```js
function setup() {
   noLoop();
   //Enable cross-origin request
  let CO = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
   //API link
  let source = 'http://hitchwiki.org/maps/api/?continent=AF';
  let url = CO + source;
  loadJSON(url, insertInToArray);
}

function insertInToArray(data) {
   var ids = [];
   var count = Object.keys(data).length;
  for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        let cod = data[i].id;
        ids[i].push(cod);
  }
     console.log(ids);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.js"></script>
```

When opening the console I get the error 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'. Apparently before all the ID's there an undefined value but I really have no clue on how to fix it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `push` put an element at the end of an array, so pushing on an index as you do with `ids[i].push(cod);` means nothing, except if the element was an array but it doesn't seem to be the case (?).

Comment: `ids[i] === undefined` try instead doing just `ids.push`

Comment: Thank you, now it works.

Comment: Not sure what exactly your `data` contains, but the JSON returned by the API is already an array: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/h4yjcfdx/ If you want to grab the ids: `var ids = data.map(e => e.id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is an array so you can use map:

```
function insertInToArray(data) {
  var ids = data.map(
    function(item){ return item.id; }
  )
  console.log(ids);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use `async` and `await` to handle my JSON requests.

```
async function insertInToArray(data) {
    ...
    var count = await Object.keys(data).length;
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

do `ids[i] = cod` instead of `ids[i].push(cod)`.

```js
function setup() {
  noLoop();
  //Enable cross-origin request
  let CO = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
  //API link
  let source = 'http://hitchwiki.org/maps/api/?continent=AF';
  let url = CO + source;
  loadJSON(url, insertInToArray);
}

function insertInToArray(data) {
  var ids = [];
  var count = Object.keys(data).length;
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    let cod = data[i].id;
    ids[i] = cod;
  }
  console.log(ids);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.js"></script>
```